# Fixed logo to content

Tags: css, responsive-design

I just can't seem to work this one out. I am needing to pin my logo to the side of my content and keep the top navigation fixed with it. I have a method to it but the problem is that it isn't responsive and eventually the logo overlaps the content. I need a solution to make this responsive or a better way of doing this. I have created a simple jsfiddle to explain what is happening so far. If you look at the full screen, the red box represents the logo and re sizing the screen you will see my issue.

Full Screen: https://jsfiddle.net/7dycmyv0/embedded/result/

Work: https://jsfiddle.net/7dycmyv0/

Here is my work so far. Any help to a better way of doing this would be appreciated. I hope this question is clear enough but if anything needs clearing up then please ask!

HTML:

```
<div class="fullwidth top_header">
<div class="top_header_wrapper"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.fullwidth {
width:100%;
}
.top_header {
position:fixed;
top:0;
right:0;
background:#8d2890;
height:39px;
}
.logo {
width:158px;
height:119px;
background:#ff0000;
position:relative;
margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.container {
height:1000px;
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1000px;
padding: 0 10px;
background:#000;
}
```

Comment: Try adding top:5px; to .logo css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the container, then set a padding on the wrapper.

That creates a situation where your content box is indented the width of your logo, and the content is centered inside of the content box.

```
<div class="wrapper"><div class="container"></div></div>

.wrapper
{
    padding:0 0 0 158px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7dycmyv0/1/

Comment: This is the best solution I have found so far. Although the logo (red box) I wanted it to hug the content (black box) and the logo to adjust down with the content. Again my other problem then is that I am not sure what to do when the screen size becomes the width of the content. I guess that is a simple media query to make the logo static and stop it from scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add a `margin-left` on your `.container`?

```css
.fullwidth { width:100%; }
.top_header { position:fixed; top:0; right:0; background:#8d2890; height:39px; }
.logo { width:158px; height:119px; background:#ff0000; position:relative; margin: 10px 0 0 10px; }
.container { height:500px; clear: both; margin: 0 auto 0 170px; max-width: 1000px; padding: 0 10px; background:#000; }
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth top_header">
    <div class="top_header_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

```css
.fullwidth { width:100%; }
.top_header { position:fixed; top:0; right:0; background:#8d2890; height:39px; }
.logo { width:158px; height:119px; background:#ff0000; position:fixed; margin: 10px 0 0 0; }
.container { height:500px; clear: both; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 1000px; padding: 0 10px; background:#000; }
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth top_header">
    <div class="top_header_wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```

Make the snippet full screen and resize it.

From what i could understand you wanted the logo to be inside the content container but fixed with the header?

Comment: Sorry if it didn't make sense, I think I am still trying to get it sorted in my head! I needed it outside the container but hugging the edge as the screen shrinks. My problem is that as the screen shrinks the logo goes over the container meaning the logo is overlaying content when scrolling up and down? Hope that makes some sense...